# KonvaJS: Layer or Group?

Tags: konvajs

I'd like to make editable and draggable text nodes: a rounded rect with text inside it.

The [Text](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Text.html) page shows first drawing the rectangle, then the text, and adding them to a Layer.  (I assume that stacks them?)

How does this compare to drawing inside a Group?  If I wanted something to be draggable, would I combine the rect and the text in a group?  Make a custom shape?

I'm trying to replicate `<div contenteditable="true" draggable="true" style="border:1px solid black;">Foo Bar!</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions for drawing such a text. Also, you can take a look into [Label shape](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Label.html).

I think the best way to organize node structures and to have more control is to create a group with text and rectangle in it. Then add that group into the layer.